sapui5 app failed to launch with error v.getLiveDependencyMap is not a function
I am developing a sapui5 app using vscode. Before, the local preview was working. But today, after previewing the app, I got the error.

And the full error in console.

My environment as following:

Sys macOS Sonoma 14.5
Node 16.20.2
npm 8.19.4
ui5 3.9.1

Project dependencies and script to start:

Many thanks!
